# find exact string in excel sheet in C# program

Tags: c#, excel

I am using c# program to search a text in my excel sheet. i have excel sheet called "MASTER" and in that sheet, there are a lot of text in column B. I want to look for 
 text "apple" inside column B. here is my code:

```
Excel.Worksheet workSheet;
workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["MASTER"];
string result;
string utterance = "apples";

range1 = workSheet.Columns["B:B"] as Excel.Range;
Excel.Range findRange 
findRange = range1.Find(utterance);
result = (string) (range2.Cells[findRange1.Row, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2;
```

it can search through the column B for input utterance "apples". however, in that column, there are a lot of apples. "applepie", "applejam","apple", etc. and the result from above code is "applepie". I think it because it just find the text contain "apple". my question is how to make it find the exact string so the output will be "apple" from column B?

Comment: See the [Excel Range documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), specifically the `_LookAt_` parameter.

Comment: You're going to have to specify a number of parameters that default to the unused default value or the last used value. `Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart` will be one, `Excel.xlmatchcase.true` might be another.

Comment: I change the input into findRange = range1.Find(utterance,Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole); however, error mismatch comes

Comment: Try range1.Find(utterance, LookIn:=xlvalues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Its VBA code. you need to find equivalent in c#

Comment: Why the [asp] tag on this? This doesn't appear to have anything to do with ASP. Also, you should specify which version of ASP you're referring to (classic, core, web forms, mvc...) - simply saying "ASP" isn't particularly meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range.Find` has many other arguments (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_Find_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlSearchDirection_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_)), especially `LookAt`, see demo below:

```
var app = new Excel.Application();
var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Path\\File.xlsx");
var sheet = workbook.Worksheets["MASTER"];
var range = (Excel.Range)sheet.Columns["B:B"];
var result = range.Find("apples", LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole);
var address = result.Address;//cell address
var value = result.Value2;//cell value
//close or do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `Split`, to treat every word as an array element

```
range1 = workSheet.Columns["B:B"] as Excel.Range;
var words = range1.Split(' ');
foreach(var word in words)
{
    if (word == utterance)
        Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```